# docker/linux aspnet core 2.03 truncating post data. How is this possible?

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core

I am at a loss and would welcome any and all advice.  This code is deceptively simple, but Async might be complicating things and causing issues.

POST method works when data bytes is less than 3802.  Data is truncated at 3800 or 3801 when the POST data is greater than 3802.  This took a while to catch for us because most of the time data is < 3800.  I finally added the debug logging and saw the disconnect.

I have been doing extra reading on async and don't currently believe this code has an issue.  I know async void will cause fire and forget, but we have a try/catch, so I expect errors to show up in the logs without taking the whole program out due to an exception.  I would welcome suggestions for improvement however.

```
[HttpPost("{instance}/{objectType}")]
    public async void Post(  [FromRoute] string instance,  [FromRoute] string objectType )
    {
        Log.Debug("Incoming post(instance/objectype)");
        string content = "";
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // have a scenario where conlen below is always cut off at 3800 or 3801 bytes
                // wild guess is that it is a async/threadpool issue?
                content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            var conlen = (content != null) ? content.Length : 0;
            var contentbegin = (content != null) ? content.Substring(0, Math.Min(conlen, 80)) : "";
            Log.Debug("POST {objecttype} {contentlen} {contentbegin}", objectType, conlen, contentbegin);

            await ProcessPost(objectType, content, instance);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Exception in Post {msg} {trace}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            Log.Error("Exception in Post offending message {msg} ", content);
        }

    }
```

Here is an example of the logs.  You can see the size of the data is > 3800, but alas, we are getting cut off when we go to read it.

```
[19:27:57 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.0 POST http://backend.example.com/orderinput application/json 5459
[19:27:57 INF] Executing action method Controllers.ValuesController.Post (Test) with arguments (["Production", "orderinput"]) - ModelState is Valid
[19:27:57 DBG] Incoming post(instance/objectype)
[19:27:57 INF] Executed action Controllers.ValuesController.Post (Test) in 0.4701ms
[19:27:57 INF] Request finished in 0.789ms 200 
[19:27:57 DBG] POST orderinput 3801 {"SAMPLE":"1234567890......... 
[19:27:57 DBG] Enter ProcessPost
[19:27:57 DBG] Persisting post
[19:27:57 ERR] Exception in ProcessPost DB Persist Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'customer_id', line 1, position 3801.
```

**EDITS:**

*WHY DO I THINK THIS CODE IS AN ISSUE?*

At the end of line 1 in the logs, ASP.NET has helpfully put the content length, 5459.  Line 6 has my calculation and it shows 3801.  These two numbers are always the same unless the length exceeds 3802.

*HOW IS THE DATA SUBMITTED?  HAVE I TRIED DOING SO?*

Data is coming from another web service not under my control through an NGINX proxy.  Thanks for the suggestion I will exercise this both with and without the proxy, above and below 3802 and report the results back here.  Given the disconnect between the ASP.NET logs and my calculation, it seems like a long shot, but all roads are worth going down.

Comment: What makes you think this code is the issue? What happens if you POST to a non-async method? Why don't you suspect the caller? What happens if you use a debugging proxy such as Fiddler, what does that see?

Comment: How are you submitting the data? If you send a 10K payload from Postman, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw away the codebase that was written by another developer and started over from scratch to fix this issue.  I think the fact that sync/async was being mixed indiscriminately was the issue, and this weird symptom was the result.  I used nito asyncex in my final solution to isolate the rabbit library from Async calls, and for the Asp.Net web API, I had all incoming data post to a queue, and the queue ran in a separate thread that exclusively talked to rabbit.  No issues at all since the rewrite.